# How to insert an event as - Out Office

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm currently working with Google-Calendar-API and trying to insert a new "Out Of Office" event in my google calendar.

I'm using the following code to insert an event:

```
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $calendarId     = 'primary';
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event([
            'summary'       => 'Summery Tets',
            'description'   => 'DescriptionTest',
            'start'         => ['dateTime' => '2019-01-14T09:00:00-07:00'],
            'end'           => ['dateTime' => '2019-01-14T10:00:00-07:00'],
            'reminders'     => ['useDefault' => false],
            'transparency'  => 'opaque',
        ]);
    $results = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

and it inserts an event - no problems, but i want it to be a "Out Of Office"-Event. I have been reading the calendar API DOC, but cant find anything about the out of office "function"

API Doc: https://developers.google.com/calendar/

Comment: It does not exist yet, but a feature request has already been made at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122674818 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112063903

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your reply, that makes a lot more sense then :). Is their any way for me to get the functionality with an normal event? (i would like it to make me unable to get invited to events in the duration or similar)

Comment: I don't think that kind of feature exist yet since this is quite a new feature to be implemented in Google Calendar. However, other calendar product API might have this feature